# Vite - Cannot import url assets in SCSS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, vite

The project is React Typescript and SASS.

I migrated from *CRA* to *Vite* and have a problem that *Vite* cannot resolve the `url(...)` in `.scss` file.

I tried to build and get the error that

[image: vite build error]

This is the project structure has been streamlined:

[image: project structure streamlined]

Inside **_index.scss**

```
.icon {
    mask-image: url("../../assets/chart-bar-solid.svg");
}
```

The **vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/google.accounts": "^0.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vite": "^4.2.1"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bson": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2"
},
```

I have tried to seek for solutions but haven't. It's welcome if you need more information to reproduce or investigate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I used `mask-image` CSS property in **_index.scss** and also used *Edge browser* in the development process.

```
.icon {
    mask-image: url("../../assets/chart-bar-solid.svg");
}
```

For `mask-image`, the *Edge browser* can't recognize it and mark it as an **Unknow property name**, instead of it, the *Edge browser* could only work with the `-webkit-mask-image` properly. Furthermore, *Vite* default build option does not support CSS vendor prefixes, causing the problem.

My solution is to add `autoprefixer` to *Vite* build configuration.

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        autoprefixer,
      ],
    },
  },
});
```